# How to write a multiple click function that targets different divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have numerous buttons on a page.  Each is related to its own separate div on the page.  When button 1 is clicked div 1 is shown.  When button 2 is clicked div 2 is shown and so on.

What's the best way to write the following jQuery below, so I don't have to keep writing a new function for every new button and new div that will need to be added?

```js
$("#bio-1").click(function () {
     $('.one').toggle(); 
});


 $("#bio-2").click(function () {
     $('.two').toggle(); 
});

$("#bio-3").click(function () {
     $('.three').toggle(); 
});

$("#bio-4").click(function () {
     $('.four').toggle(); 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using ***data-**** attribute which on clicking you can use to find only the specific element to toggle.

**Demo:**

```js
$("[id^=bio-").click(function () {
  $(`div[data-id=${this.id}]`).toggle(); 
});
```

```css
div{
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid lightgray;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="bio-1">Button-1</button>
<button id="bio-2">Button-2</button>
<button id="bio-3">Button-3</button>
<button id="bio-4">Button-4</button>

<div class="one" data-id="bio-1">One</div>
<div class="two" data-id="bio-2">Two</div>
<div class="three" data-id="bio-3">Three</div>
<div class="four" data-id="bio-4">Four</div>
```

Comment: I was preparing a snippet with the exact same approach.. no need :)

Comment: I posted mine because your toggle function is not working properly! Reinitialize the display logic... and update your answer so you keep my Upvote :)

Comment: @Bilel, since OP is using `toggle()` in each click, I think he does not want to show them always:)

Comment: Weird but possible :) Right ! Keep it then... I already explained that in my answer. And that's why I avoided to use toggle() in my answer. He/She decides what fits to the expected design

Comment: @Bilel, OP clearly asking for the optimisation not the design:)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you initialize your display... hidden or all visible divs. This is like a toggle based on a common identifier that would let you keep your actual HTML code and shorten and organize your javascript code.

To use a toggle function, you should initialize your styles following the expected visibility logic.

```js
$('div[data-id!=""]').hide();
$("[id^=bio-]").on("click", function () {
$('div[data-id!=""]').hide();
$('div[data-id="'+$(this).data('id')+'"]').show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="bio-1" data-id="1">One</button>
<button id="bio-2" data-id="2">Two</button>
<button id="bio-3" data-id="3">Three</button>
<button id="bio-4" data-id="4">Four</button>

<div class="one" data-id="1">One</div>
<div class="two" data-id="2">Two</div>
<div class="three" data-id="3">Three</div>
<div class="four" data-id="4">Four</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Demo**
you have to used toggle as well as show jquery function.

```js
$(".clickBUtton").click(function () {
    var id = this.id; // click class id      
    $("#DIV"+id).show(); // toggle and you also add show
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clickBUtton" id="one">ONE</button>
<button class="clickBUtton" id="two">TWO</button>

<div id="DIVone" style="display:none;">one div</div>
<div id="DIVtwo" style="display:none;">two div</div>
```